# access environment variables from .yaml

Tags: node.js, dotenv

I'm using express and AppEngine. I have my environments variables in .yaml file and I don't access them using dotenv.

For example, **.secrets.yaml**

```
env_variables:
         test: "test1234"
```

This is my **index.js**

```
import 'dotenv/config';
console.log(process.env.test);
```

I get "undefined".
I tried passing path of my file but it didn't work.

Comment: I think dotenv only supports dotfiles like `.env` in the format `test = "test1234`. Also make sure the `.env` file is at the root or specify the path of the file using the `config` method. Also dotenv is suitable for development purposes. Maybe the AppEngine injects the environment variable at runtime in your docker container.

Comment: Try adding checks like `if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') { import 'dotenv/config'; ` then import the dotenv module.

Comment: Hello, how I get the value of NODE_ENV if I use secrets manager of Google Cloud?
So always I gonna need a .env file?

Comment: ideally you should set environment variables like `NODE_ENV` to distiguish the environment.

Comment: Try copying the environment variables under `env_variables` key in a .env file in `KEY = VALUE` format